Storybook Actions not consistent when using boolean function handler
I am trying to write a Storybook story in React that displays the output of a function handler on a component, using Storybook Actions. However, each event displays either the value itself, or an object with the name of the action and the args.
For example:
onClick: {name: "onClick", args: false}
onClick: true
onClick: {name: "onClick", args: false}
onClick: true
onClick: {name: "onClick", args: false}
onClick: true

Why is storybook outputting onClick: {name: "onClick", args: false} instead of
onClick: false? Or vice versa, why not display onClick: {name: "onClick", args: true} instead of onClick: true?
Story Code:

const Template = (args) => (
    <MyComponent {...args}/>
);

const Default = Template.bind({});

Default.argTypes = {
  onClick: {
    description:
      "A callback function that is called when the user changes the state of the checkbox.",
    action: "onClick",
  },
};

Component Code:
const MyComponent = ({ onClick }) => (  
  <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => onClick(e.target.checked)} />
);

I am using "@storybook/react": "^6.2.9".
